# Alinging elements in EA through Addin

Tags: enterprise-architect

When the diagramobjects are created using addin using API parentDiagram.DiagramObjects.AddNew("l=30;r=700;t=-50;b=-450;", "") we have first parameter in AddNew method where we will be able to set the position left,right,top and bottom.for these alignment we assign integer values .So we have around 20 elements created in diagram so we have one formula where it will be generating the integer values based on previous diagramobject top,left,bottom,right values.So is there any boundary for these integer values.
For Ex:left can have only integer values from 0-2000.

Comment: You need to align diagram objects in a diagram..? If soi y don't you just use LayoutDiagram property  in API call

Comment: I don't think there are limits (other then data type limits) to the values you can pass. Question is of course if it is wise to add so many elements to a diagram that you have to wonder about the limits ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can set all the EA given layout's in your diagram through **LayoutDiagram** property of GetProjectInterface.

Using below code it can be achieved :

```
 Repository.GetProjectInterface().LayoutDiagram(DiagramUGID,layoutStyle);
```

Comment: The posted image contains copyrighted material. It's from Sparx Systems' help file for Enterprise Architect.

Comment: @Uffe Yep Removed, Thanks for info